# Styling Specific Pages or Elements of a Specific Page of a Wordpress Site with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tailwind-css

I have an existing WordPress site that is running on a Front End Theme, Divi. This is a Major Site with almost 250k Visitors a Month and the Design and content is kind of getting old.

I'd started learning and practising to create my own sites using Gatsby and Strapi however, the commitment to rebuild this site again from scratch would be weeks if not months.

I googled up how to use Tailwind CSS on my WordPress site, the results were directing me in creating a new theme. but then I would have to use another plugin that would allow me to use multiple themes on a single site.

Can I instead use Tailwind and either Vanilla HTML or JSX on a page instead of going through the theme path. The changes that I'll be making are mostly front end based and honestly speaking Divi sucks in creating the design I'm trying to go ahead with.

The site I'm discussing is [www.deltamotocorp.com](http://www.deltamotocorp.com) and I would like to only make changes to certain elements on certain pages and slowly I could get approval for a complete rebuild for the same.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a separate technology, such as tailwind-CSS for a site that has been built with standard CSS techniques.  The reason is if anyone other than you would need to work on the site, it would make that person's life a misery. It also shows in the design.

The website does not look that outdated.  I agree some elements could need adjustment.  I found the site, although it looks very simple, is a bit disorganized.

Sometimes, taking on fixes is much more work.  It's like buying pants 5 years ago and trying to change the style of pockets and zipper or width of the legs.

Give the project owner an idea what would need changing, cost, etc. and if really necessary, tell them a new site would not only be visually more pleasing and technologically more advanced, it could give the chance to organize it better, and the price would be less than fixing.

A better upgrade would be an e-commerce website with a search button, etc.

I hope you get the approval for a new site, but don't mish/mash things.
Keep it clean, keep it clear for others as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did the same thing as you've suggested and started building a New Website on GatsbyJS with Tailwind.